# Command Prompt output to CSV

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, command-line, batch-file, csv

I'm using the forfiles command to list files and folders (included sub folders) which is piped to a text file. My subsequent process requires this output to be in comma delimited format (.csv).

This is the script I'm currently using and would like to update:

forfiles /s /C "cmd /c echo @file @fdate @ftime @isdir" > MyTextOutput.txt

Is it possible to send the output from the forfiles command to a .csv file?

Comment: well, put quotes around each field,  a comma between each , and a newline at the end of a record. then after export, just rename the file to have a .csv extension.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow?

Comment: CSV is a text file, where each field (@file, @fdate, etc) is seperated by a comma (hence comma seperated value), and each record is delimited by a newline character. use quotes around each feild in case they contain a comma. saving a text document with these characteristics makes it a CSV, even if the file extension is differant. that means that once export is complete, you can just rename MyTextOutput.txt to MyTextOutput.csv.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
forfiles /s /C "cmd /c echo @file, @fdate, @ftime, @isdir" > MyTextOutput.csv
```

You are telling the OS what to output, just tell it to output commas too.